# Duvida de como pular de 7 em 7 nos ids do próprio onItemClickListener android

Tags: android, condição

Como fazer uma condição no qual ele vai pular de 7 em 7 pois estou tendo que definir isso manualmente na mão, e se tiver dados a cima dos ids definidos, ele vai dar erro ai complicaria . Abaixo um exemplo do código ao qual preciso diminuir e fazer com que ele some sempre 7 ,enquanto existir itens na listview:

```
if (id_item_titulo == 0 ||id_item_titulo == 7 || id_item_titulo == 14 || id_item_titulo == 21 || id_item_titulo == 28 || id_item_titulo == 35
                    || id_item_titulo == 42 || id_item_titulo == 49 || id_item_titulo == 56 || id_item_titulo == 63
                    || id_item_titulo == 70 || id_item_titulo == 77 || id_item_titulo == 85 || id_item_titulo == 92
                    || id_item_titulo == 99 || id_item_titulo == 106 || id_item_titulo == 111 || id_item_titulo == 118
                    || id_item_titulo == 125 || id_item_titulo == 132) {

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parece um caso para o [operador de resto `%`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html):

```
// Se o ID for múltiplo de 7...
// Em outras palavras, se o resto da divisão por 7 for zero...
if(id_item_titulo % 7 == 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No caso ele depois vai pra 14,21,28 e por ai vai em 7 em 7 automaticamente ? Quero evitar de ficar definindo os valores dos IDS clicado.

Comment: Ele não "vai" para lugar nenhum, mas só vai entrar no `if` se o ID for múltiplo de 7, ou zero. Exemplo: http://ideone.com/OkRJvV

Comment: Fiquei intrigado com a sua pergunta acima, e achei que saber isto talvez te ajudasse: `id_item_titulo % 7` é uma *expressão* onde `%` é o *operador*, e o que tem em volta dele são os *operandos*. Essa expressão retorna um valor (o resto da divisão por 7), que é em seguida comparado com o valor zero.

Comment: Amigo, chegando em casa eu irei tentar essa idéia, e volto aqui para lhe informar se consegui ou não, lhe agradeço já antecipadamente.

Comment: Obrigado, coloquei  if  (id_do_item % 2 == 0 || id_do_item % 2== 1 ) {
//****


}
 e funcionou : )

Comment: Mas @DiegoKappaun, isso que você colocou não pula de 7 em 7!

Comment: O de 7 em 7 era para fazer uma ação só de um determinado item, só que eu coloquei aquela nova condição para pegar em todos e diminuir o tamanho do código .Tinha posto uma condição na outra classe de ao clicar no espaço em branco ele não abrir uma activity, enquanto os outros podiam normalmente, e já na classe que defini essa condição nova, eles podiam ser pares e impares , então não tive problemas de acrescentar e fazer update de todos os itens  .

Comment: Mas... mas... `if (id_do_item % 2 == 0 || id_do_item % 2== 1 )` não faz sentido! Qualquer número inteiro será sempre par *ou* ímpar. Então você nem precisa do `if`. @DiegoKappaun

Comment: Fiz testes e quando coloco multiplos métodos dentro do IF com apenas a condição diferente, ele executa apenas o do item que da resto 0 e eu preciso que seja 0 e 1 para que os outros itens sejam alterados sem problemas, é que minha forma de criar o programa foi um pouco diferente .